# Point Feature Histograms Calculation

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

To compute a single PFH representation from a k-neighborhood, we use:

```
computePointPFHSignature (const pcl::PointCloud<PointInT> &cloud,
                          const pcl::PointCloud<PointNT> &normals,
                          const std::vector<int> &indices,
                          int nr_split,
                          Eigen::VectorXf &pfh_histogram);
```

How can I calculate vector indices which  represents the set of k-nearest neighbors from cloud?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/59814/point-feature-histograms-calculation./) by [Nihad](https://answers.ros.org/users/4554/nihad/) on ROS Answers with karma: 22 on 2013-04-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You might consider using the [PFHEstimation](http://docs.pointclouds.org/1.5.1/classpcl_1_1_f_p_f_h_estimation.html) class, as it already handles this for you.  See the PCL tutorial [here](http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/fpfh_estimation.php#fpfh-estimation) for more details.

If you want to do the search manually, you'll want to use the [`kdtree`](http://docs.pointclouds.org/1.5.1/classpcl_1_1_kd_tree_f_l_a_n_n.html) class for that, as shown in [this](http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/kdtree_search.php#kdtree-search) tutorial:

```
int K = 10;
std::vector<int> KNNidx(K);
std::vector<float> KNNdist(K);
pcl::KdTreeFLANN<pcl::PointXYZ> kdtree;
for (int idx=0; idx<cloud.size(); ++idx) {
  kdtree.nearestKSearch(cloud, idx, K, KNNidx, KNNdist);
  computePointPFHSignature(cloud, normals, KNNidx, nr_split, pfh_hist);
  ...do something with pfh_hist...
}
```

---

Originally posted by [Jeremy Zoss](https://answers.ros.org/users/3925/jeremy-zoss/) with karma: 4976 on 2013-04-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0